# How to childproof small table intentionally away from wall?

Tags: child-safety

I have a small table next to a rocking chair in my child’s nursery. Once my child starts crawling and walking, I want everything in the nursery to be childproofed, including the table. While I could fasten the tab to the wall, that moves it away from the rocker, thereby defeating its purpose.

Is there any way to childproof a small table that’s away from walls?

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, I assume your "childproof" means to fasten the table down so that it cannot be moved or tipped over, rather than to cover the sharp edges.

If both the table and your floor allow you to put in some fasteners, the simple solution would be use a **corner brace** like this to fasten your table to the floor:
[image]

Comment: Forgot to mention the floor is carpeted. Could such fasteners be used without damaging the carpet?

Comment: Strictly speaking the fasteners (e.g. #6 screws, with a diameter of 0.13in or 3.5mm) will damage the carpet. However this size of hole on most carpet is not noticeable.